# How do you attach a function to a button in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, button

I'm new to programming. I was making an SMS app. I don't know how to attach a function to a button. Here is the activity, and the xml.

```
    public void sendSMS() {
    Log.d("TAG", "button is now clicked");
    String phoneNumber = "443*******";
    String message = "Hello! How are you?";

    SmsManager; SmsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    SmsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}

          <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send Message" />
```

How are you supposed to attach a function to a button?

Thanks, I appreciate your time.

Comment: Have a look at this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want is to make use of the onClick attribute.

Add this attribute to your Button element:

```
android:onClick="sendSMS"
```

Android will then try to call a sendSMS method in your activity. It takes a View as a parameter (which will be set to the view you clicked) so you need to change your method to:

```
public void sendSMS(View view)
```

This is all covered in the documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html